# Books about non-euclidean geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, resource-recommendations

I study physics and want to know the best books to learn non-euclidean geometry in an easy way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book covering differential geometry and topology required for physics and applications](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29956/)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform sorry can you tell me for what branches of physics are these books used?Thank you

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  yes and those in the question Book covering differential geometry and topology required for physics and applications

Comment: well then I have to study this too

Comment: Interesting that this got closed. Non-Euclidean geometry literature tend to have a very different flavor from Riemannian geometry literature.