# What is a good book for self learning in geometry and topology and physics?

Tags: differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, topology

I am a graduate student in physics. I want to self-study topology geometry and physics. I use the book of Nakahara with the same title. However, this book is not convenient for self-study in my opinion. I have the following problems while studying this book;

- There are not enough number of examples. When a mathematical definition is given, it is very easy to misunderstand it. And it is very hard to have an intuition on the idea presented. The definitions and the presentation are very concise, so in order have a feeling of what actually the presented ideas means, I usually need to address youtube to see whether someone explained already, however not everything is on youtube.
- There is an inconsistency on the notation, and there are also typos. So if you are learning it for the first time, this inconsistency can made some concepts impossible to grasp.

The good part of this book is, the topics covered are exactly what I need.

Thus do you have any book to complement this book with a more intuitive explanation, which is self-study friendly, and with more examples. Or even better, do you know any book that treats the same topic in a more pedagogical manner.
I specifically ask a book that covers same topics with  Nakahara's chapters 2-10  which is pedagogical and suitable for self-learning, or a book to complement this one.

[the contents of the nakahara's book is here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750306068)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book covering differential geometry and topology for physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29956/)

Comment: Can I suggest you put a link to the book cited, so users can see which topics you think the book covers well,  despite its other issues?

Comment: Your Amazon link suggests Nash & Sen as an alternative. It has 16 customer reviews. That's probably (at least) 15 more than you would get here. :) If you want a book with lots of examples, look at Schaum's Outline series. Plenty of suggestions on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=topology+geometry+physics+&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Atopology+geometry+physics+)

Comment: Try Chris Ishams book, *Modern Differential Geometry for Physicists*. I think there is a similar problem with this book though - there aren't enough examples. This seems to be a generic problem of books of this kind. They spend so many pages explaining the technology that they barely leave enough to explain the applications. The last chapter is very good though in connecting the formalism of principal bundles to the notation used in physics. He is also very careful with notation and so it's consistent all the way through.

Comment: This, in my opinion, makes the book dense even if the ideas are straight-forward enough. It's a matter of grasping the ideas and then being comfortable enough to work with them.

Comment: Another book that is very good is Michors, *Natural Operations in Differential Geometry*. It is available free  online. This is orientated towards mathematicians though, and has far too much material for the average physicist. However the first three chapters on Manifolds, Vector Bundles and Principal Bundles are worth the trouble in the way they spell out all the material in a consistent and rigorous fashion.