# Looking for textbook on differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, education

I am looking for a textbook(s) that discusses differential geometry, smooth manifolds etc. More precisely, I have been trying to find a textbook that covers the following topics:

1. Differential geometry ( vector fields, forms, manifolds, mappings between manifolds, bundles, etc)
2. Fibre bundle application to physics
3. Lie theory and differential geometry
4. Includes (or has some) illustrations

I am looking for something that is rigorous but not completely terse like a pure mathematics book, but also not so physical. I have found Marian's Fecko's book good however, the whole idea of working out and deriving definitions is not something I am particularly fond of. I have also read Isham's text and found myself needing to look up a lot of things to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Nakahara's *Topology, Geometry, and Physics* has everything that you describe and more and is terrific!

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29956/2451 ad links therein.

Comment: I will give a piece of advice. Usually physicists want to learn math, but they look for something which is “more like Physics style”. I recommend avoiding this mindset and really studying the math as it is. This will allow you later on to use it in a much better way. That said my suggestion is Spivak’s “A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry”. Isham’s book can also come in handy.

Comment: My usual advice for this question is not a book, but the lectures of Frederic Schuller: [General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6YPgEhGKjOGKriFcF0LCJ4J8LDY3-nyR) and [Geometric Anatomy of Physics](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic).  They are not books, but they are quite complete and give you the base understanding and confidence to read technical books on the subject. They are mathematical in nature, but make connections to physics (e.g., the GR lectures are 12 lectures of math, followed by 12 lectures of their applications in GR).